# Django query passing parameters into values()

Tags: python, sql, django, database, parameters

I have a Django query like this and I want to be able to pass the "values" param from a variable. Reason for this I can standardize all my list values otherwise it will be hardcoded on every values.

So for example, this works:

```
employee_list = Employee.objects.all().values("id", "username").order_by('id')
```

But I cannot do this. It doesnt work:

```
val_params = ["id", "username"]
employee_list = Employee.objects.all().values(val_params).order_by('id')
```

what kind of val_params can i use to pass into values() ? Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Can you please try this `employee_list = Employee.objects.all().values(*val_params).order_by('id') `

Comment: it worked! I'd be happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
employee_list = Employee.objects.all().values(*val_params).order_by('id')
```